Science fiction about a science post on the edge of the galaxy
I remember reading a novel about a science post on the edge of the galaxy. An alien lands and proceeds to mess with everyone. They end up having an orgy and the station is mostly destroyed. A woman ends up having to have her brain implanted into the station computer to warn earth about the alien. I don't remember the name or author.
